# MS Access calculated fields changing to "#Error"

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I currently have a form that runs off of a query and everything works swimmingly, or at least it appears.  I have three fields in question: an ID field, a Client Name field, and an Age field.  The age field is actually the client's age at the signing of the quote, so it is a calculated field using the date of the quote and the client's DOB.

The age calculation works perfectly upon first look.  The reason the ID and name fields are in question are because when I double click them it opens a form, which yet again works fine.  The problem is when I exit those forms and come back to the original form.

The age field of whatever record I was on changes to "#Error" instead of what it was displaying.  If i click on a different record in the form then that age field changes to "#Error" as well.  This seems to happen every time and I have no clue why.

Has anyone solved an issue similar to this or have an idea on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Update: I changed it to open a report rather than a Form and the issue is still there.

The calculation in question: Int(([effectiveDate]-[dateOfBirth])/365.25)

Comment: When you say calculated field, do you mean you have a calculated field on the form or report? or a calculated field in your table? Can you post the actual calculation?

Comment: Without any code you leave us guessing ...

Comment: The field is calculated in the query.  Here is the code.  Sorry for not giving enough info!                                                                                     Int(([effectiveDate]-[dateOfBirth])/365.25)

Comment: sounds like something in your subform/second form is trashing the results of your main/first form.  can you view both forms at the same time and step through the code on the 2nd form to see which step triggers the change?

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating age this way:

```
DateDiff("yyyy", [dateOfBirth], [effectiveDate]) + ([effectiveDate] < DateSerial(Year([effectiveDate]), Month([dateOfBirth]), Day([dateOfBirth])))
```

Using this method takes the difference in years between your date of birth and the effective date, taking into account that the person's birthday may not have passed yet by that date.

Basically the first part gets the years and the second part either adds 0 for false or adds -1 for true if the effective date is LESS than the birthday for the effective year (meaning it hadn't passed yet)

Comment: That didn't work.  It actually returned error on everything for that not ever showing the correct data unlike the other method :/